# Whats best way to debug Android JNI/C++ application in eclipse?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Android 2.2, NDK R7 Eclipse.  Whats best way to debug C++ code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps this can help solve your questions 
[Using Eclipse for Android C/C++ Debugging](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/)

Comment: I'm going to try this, and if it works I'll follow up.

Comment: Either way I will post how it worked for me thanks.

Comment: If you don't like bumbling around with gdb and its ilk - [ARM](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/ds-5/community-edition/index.php) released a pretty nifty toolchain for free (for small companies and individual developers).

Comment: I'll take a look at this tool as well. Thanks

Comment: @Androider followps?